# Redirection in location.path() AngularJS method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, spring-boot

**app.js**

```
   .when('/ModifyStructure/{c}', {
            templateUrl: 'views/ModifyStructure.html',
            controller: 'ModifyStructureCTRL'
          }
```

**method**

```
 $scope.editST = function (ids) {
         var c = ids.substring(1, 3);
         $location.path('http://localhost:8080/structure/ModifyStructure/' + c);
     }
```

why when excuting this method , the navigator redirect me to the '/' path ?

Comment: Try using `$location.path('/ModifyStructure/' + c);`

Answer (score 1):

> why when excuting this method , the navigator redirect me to the '/' path ?

Because what you are trying to set is not a *path*, it's an absolute URL. However, in the documentation it [explicitly states](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) that in Angular:

> Path should always begin with forward slash (/), this method will add the forward slash if it is missing.

In your case, you since there is no such path defined in route configuration, `otherwise` section is executed, which I assume has redirect to `/`.

You should assign a path like this instead:

```
$location.path('/ModifyStructure/' + c);
```

Comment: ok it's done, but the problem no is how to get the value of "c" in the ModifyStructure.html page ?

Comment: Use`$routeParams` service in `ModifyStructureCTRL`. The you can expose it to scope: `$scope.c = $routeParams.c`.

Comment: after using alert($routeParams.c) it display "undefined" ??

Comment: I think it should be `.when('/ModifyStructure/:c', {`

Comment: it's the same probleme  it display "undefined" ??